# Which SSIS executable is best practise to use for delete command

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbcommand

I have 2 DB's on same SQL 2016 std. server. I need to delete Prod table data that matches ID's in the Arh DB table. I am doing this in batches of 10000 rows.
Table's on Prod and Arh DB are with same schema.
I need to delete a large amount of data (aprox. 3000000 rows).
I use OLE DB command executable with SQL statement but it is slow as hell.
Is there chance to speed up this.

Comment: In general one should soft-delete 1st and then eventually delete all as a whole at quite times because I think a lot of locking occurs. There are also other things to be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955435/optimizing-delete-on-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using OLEDB Command within a data flow task (which performs delete operation row by row), you can simply use an `Execute SQL Task` and write a delete command with join:

```
DELETE T1
FROM Prod T1 INNER JOIN Arch T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
```

If you are handling millions of rows you can delete rows in batches:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

    DELETE TOP(100000) 
    FROM Prod 
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 From Arch WHERE Prod.id = Arch.id)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1 BREAK

END
```

**References**

- [How to Delete Top(N) rows with an inner join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052979/how-to-delete-topn-rows-with-an-inner-join)